# Sagemath 9.2 documentation not working on Ubuntu Focal

Tags: sage

I've downloaded the Sage 9.2 tarball from sagemath.org for Ubuntu Focal. The software works in every other regard but when I load a Jupyter notebook and click on one of the Help topics, I get a 404 File not Found saying the page I'm requesting doesn't exist.

How do I get the docs to work? Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Sage 9.2. See

- [Ask Sage question 54581: 9.2 download for Ubuntu 20.04 documentation](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/54581)
- [Sage-Windows issue 52: broken symbolic link: doc -> /doesnotexist/html/en](https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/issues/52)

The issue is fixed at the following ticket,
which was merged in Sage 9.3.beta3:

- [Sage Trac ticket 30903: Fix broken symlink to documentation in the Sage jupyter kernelspec](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/30903)

Two solutions to get the fix:

- wait for Sage 9.3 in a few weeks
- install 9.3.beta3

One can also fix one's installation as suggested
at Sage-Windows issue 52 referenced above.

For this run the following commands:

```
$ SR=`sage -c 'print(SAGE_ROOT)'`
$ A=$SR/local/share/doc/sage/html/en
$ B=$SR/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sagemath/doc
$ ln -sf $A $B
```

This works fine and restarting Sage is not even needed.